# Is this a bug? A list overwriting another due to its name being similar?

Tags: python

I am really puzzled on this one, it seems the second list overwrites the first one, when there is absolutely no connection between them -- they are 2 different lists. If not a bug, could someone please explain me why? Thank you.

EDIT: The runeWay_add list overwrites the runeWay_sub list, when they are 2 different lists. In the end, I reconstruct the procedure with solely runeWay_sub and it works like it should.

```
>>> rune_cynumbers
[[53, 23, 67, 7, 17, 71, 31, 97, 2], [15, 8, 18, 3, 6, 19, 10, 24, 0], [16, 9, 19, 4, 7, 20, 11, 25, 1], [53, 23, 41, 67, 17, 71, 31, 107, 2], [15, 8, 12, 18, 6, 19, 10, 27, 0], [16, 9, 13, 19, 7, 20, 11, 28, 1]]
>>> rune_keynumbers
[[59, 23, 67, 31, 29, 53, 59, 97, 11], [16, 8, 18, 10, 9, 15, 16, 24, 4], [17, 9, 19, 11, 10, 16, 17, 25, 5], [5, 59, 67, 31, 29, 53, 59, 97, 11], [2, 16, 18, 10, 9, 15, 16, 24, 4], [3, 17, 19, 11, 10, 16, 17, 25, 5]]
>>> runeWay_sub = []
>>> runeWay_add = []
>>> for SET in rune_keynumbers:
...   micro_array = []
...   for i in SET:
...     micro_array.append(0)
...   runeWay_add.append(micro_array)
...   runeWay_sub.append(micro_array)
... 
>>> runeWay_add
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> runeWay_sub
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> for SET in enumerate(rune_keynumbers):
...   for i in enumerate(SET[1]):
...     runeWay_sub[SET[0]][i[0]] = rune_cynumbers[SET[0]][i[0]] - rune_keynumbers[SET[0]][i[0]]
...     runeWay_add[SET[0]][i[0]] = rune_cynumbers[SET[0]][i[0]] + rune_keynumbers[SET[0]][i[0]]
... 
>>> runeWay_sub
[[112, 46, 134, 38, 46, 124, 90, 194, 13], [31, 16, 36, 13, 15, 34, 26, 48, 4], [33, 18, 38, 15, 17, 36, 28, 50, 6], [58, 82, 108, 98, 46, 124, 90, 204, 13], [17, 24, 30, 28, 15, 34, 26, 51, 4], [19, 26, 32, 30, 17, 36, 28, 53, 6]]
>>> runeWay_add
[[112, 46, 134, 38, 46, 124, 90, 194, 13], [31, 16, 36, 13, 15, 34, 26, 48, 4], [33, 18, 38, 15, 17, 36, 28, 50, 6], [58, 82, 108, 98, 46, 124, 90, 204, 13], [17, 24, 30, 28, 15, 34, 26, 51, 4], [19, 26, 32, 30, 17, 36, 28, 53, 6]]
>>> import sys; print sys.version
2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2]
>>> runeWay_sub = []
>>> for SET in rune_keynumbers:
...   micro_array = []
...   for i in SET:
...     micro_array.append(0)
...   runeWay_sub.append(micro_array)
...
>>> runeWay_sub
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> for SET in enumerate(rune_keynumbers):
...   for i in enumerate(SET[1]):
...     runeWay_sub[SET[0]][i[0]] = rune_cynumbers[SET[0]][i[0]] - rune_keynumbers[SET[0]][i[0]]
... 
>>> runeWay_sub
[[-6, 0, 0, -24, -12, 18, -28, 0, -9], [-1, 0, 0, -7, -3, 4, -6, 0, -4], [-1, 0, 0, -7, -3, 4, -6, 0, -4], [48, -36, -26, 36, -12, 18, -28, 10, -9], [13, -8, -6, 8, -3, 4, -6, 3, -4], [13, -8, -6, 8, -3, 4, -6, 3, -4]]
```

Comment: The runeWay_add list overwrites runeWay_sub as you can see. Also, you can see that there are no typos since everything was typed on an interpreter.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. Could you reduce this to a smaller, better explained example?

Comment: Although I might guess: `runeWay_sub` and `runeWay_add` are different lists, but the references they contain are to the *same* lists.

Comment: Are you really sure `runeWay_add` and `runeWay_sub` don't refer to the same list, or the same set of elements? It looks like you're appending `micro_array` to both lists, so this is the behavior you'd expect.

Comment: No there's no connection between them, I typed everything as you see it -- apart from the declaration of rune_keynumbers and rune_cynumbers which is pretty irrelevant.

@PaulGriffiths So what about the micro_array? That array constructs the 2 lists yes, but there's no connection between the 2 lists as I edit the lists inside those lists.

Comment: @usar103110: well, your `micro_array` lists are shared when you are appending to `runWay_add` and `runWay_sub`. What did you expect to happen there instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With these two lines:

```
runeWay_add.append(micro_array)
runeWay_sub.append(micro_array)
```

`runeWay_add` and `runeWay_sub` are separate lists, but you are not copying the contents of `micro_array` into each list; you are storing a reference to the list in each. As a result, when you execute

```
runeWay_sub[SET[0]][i[0]] = rune_cynumbers[SET[0]][i[0]] - rune_keynumbers[SET[0]][i[0]]
runeWay_add[SET[0]][i[0]] = rune_cynumbers[SET[0]][i[0]] + rune_keynumbers[SET[0]][i[0]]
```

the expressions `runeWay_sub[SET[0]]` and `runeWay_add[SET[0]]` both refer to the *same* list.

Here's a simpler example that demonstrates the exact same problem:

```
>>> c = [1,2,3]
>>> a = []
>>> b = []
>>> a.append(c)
>>> b.append(c)
>>> a[0][0] = 4
>>> a, b, c
([[4, 2, 3]], [[4, 2, 3]], [4, 2, 3])
```

`c`, `a[0]`, and `b[0]` all refer to the *exact* same list object, so the assignment to `a[0][0]` is visible via `a`, `b`, and `c`.

Answer (score 0):

After this:

```
>>> for SET in rune_keynumbers:
...   micro_array = []
...   for i in SET:
...     micro_array.append(0)
...   runeWay_add.append(micro_array)
...   runeWay_sub.append(micro_array)
```

`runeWay_add` and `runeWay_sub` contain the same mutable list elements, so any changes you make to the elements of one list will be shown in the other. You probably want to append a *copy* of `micro_array` to `runeWay_sub` instead:

```
runeWay_sub.append(micro_array[:])
```